# Programmatically added UIViews disappear after switching into view again with ViewDeck

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, viewdeck

**Some brief background:**

I am using [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck), which allows the app to switch between views using a slider menu similar to the one used in Facebook or Foursquare apps. In my app there is a primary view which users spend the most time on called `MainProfileView`, as well as several secondary views.  With `ViewDeck`, the view that gets displayed in the center is set such that `[self.viewDeckController setCenterController:NAME_OF_VIEW_CONTROLLER]`

**The problem:**

My issue is, when I initially set my `centerController` as `MainProfileView`, or to one of these secondary views, everything works fine.  However, when I attempt to set `centerController` as `MainProfileView` *again* after previously setting it to something else, all the views that were previously *programmatically* added to `MainProfileView` would not show, and only the ones that I added using the Storyboard shows up.  I'm unsure why this issue is occurring, and would ideally like whichever view that were previously shown in `MainProfileView` to still be there when I later set my `centerController` as it again.

Thanks!

As some background, here is how my AppDelegate is configured:

```
UIStoryboard* mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
UIViewController* menuController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuViewController"];
//UIViewController *rightController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightViewController"];
UINavigationController* centerViewController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
self.viewDeckController =  [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:centerViewController leftViewController:menuController rightViewController:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewDeckController;
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```